# I want to include the users name in the form submitted message

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code and I want to somehow change the message the users sees when they submit the form to include there name like "Ben, Your message has been sent!" I also want to keep it styled like it is now but then include the name.

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $to = "benlevygraphics@gmail.com";
            $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'];
            $subject = "Ben, you have been contacted...";
            $body = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nWebsite: " . $_POST['web'] . "\nMessage: " . $_POST['message'];

            if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){

                echo("<p class=contactformsent>Your message has been sent!</p>");
            }
            else{
               echo("<p class=contactformnotsent>Message delivery failed...</p>");
            }
       }

?>
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to add a "name" field in the form users fill in to invoke the e-mail.  Q: What other ideas were you considering?

Comment: You need some way to grab the user's name, then just put it in the echo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So insert the name into the message:

```
echo("<p class=contactformsent>".$_POST['name'].", your message has been sent!</p>");
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense unless Ben is sending an email to himself, or there are two Bens.

Comment: I'm guessing the Ben was entirely for example, it should actually be John Doe, etc.

Comment: My point is that the name of who is being contacted shouldn't use the same Post value as the name of the person DOING the contacting.

Comment: They aren't the same... one is Ben Levy, the OP and receiver of the email (apparently hard-coded).  The other is $_POST['name'], filled out by the user accessing the site, where they've typed in who they are.  Of course, we're all making educated guesses here until the OP weighs in.

Comment: Now how can I at the same time send an email to the user with a custom message if I wanted to?

Comment: Do the same thing.  Set the to, from, subject, body, and call the `mail` function.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Ill try that but where do I put that part of the code? thanks

Comment: @mellamokb I don't no where to put the code, I am not that good with php yet

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
echo("<p class=contactformsent>".$name." Your message has been sent!</p>");
```

Comment: Put the space inside the quotes: "<p class=contactformsent>".$name." Your message has been sent!</p>"

Comment: i have updated the answer, i added a space before the message. it is same as requested